# How do I properly use jQuery in the yeoman framework?

Tags: jquery, angularjs, gruntjs, yeoman, bower

For the life of me I cannot get jquery to properly work in a yeoman project.

My jquery.js isn't being seen from `jquery-scripts.js`; however, `jquery-scripts.js` is being built because I can use alerts and vanilla javascript.

How do I properly use jQuery in the yeoman framework? Where do I place my files?  How do I get jQuery methods to be reveled?

Jquery script looks as so:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){ 
    $('.container').addClass('LONGESTCLASSESVERBRA');
});
```

### I've placed this script inside `jquery-scripts.js` and put that under the scripts folder

My file structure appears as so:
[image]

---

I believe I'm just pilot error because
If I type my code into console it works just fine:
[image: longest]
[image]

Comment: Any error on the console log? Do you use jQuery code in the controller? Could you paste your source for more details?

Comment: Did you ever find an answer?  Just curious.  :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a hunch, but my guess is the `<div>` you want to modify hasn't been created by later Angular scripts you include when the jQuery `.addClass` executes in `jquery-scripts.js`.

I say this because you are able to change the DOM via the console...but that's after the DOM has been created by whatever Angular is doing to populate `ng-view`.

Given that we readers don't know what's in your `app.js` and I don't see any directives plainly called out in your directory structure, my suspicion is that `main.js`, `airports.js` or `appCtrl.js` is creating the `<div>` you want to modify with jQuery.

To quickly confirm or deny my hunch:

1. Hardcode `<div class="testjquery"></div>` just before or after `<div ng-view=""></div>`.
2. Modify your code in `jquery-scripts.js` to target `.testjquery` instead of `.container`
3. Rebuild and load the page and see if the statically created test `<div>` has a modified class.

If it worked and the hardcoded div *has* been modified, then your jQuery is executing before Angular has created the target div and class.

And if so, you might be able to quick-fix things by moving the `jquery-scripts.js` to the bottom of the `scripts.js` block so it only executes after all Angular code has triggered once.  In such a situation, this isn't the "right answer" but it will get you moving.  The right answer is probably changing your app so you don't have a `jquery-scripts.js` file and instead use Angular directives for DOM changes within `ng-view`.

If it **didn't** work and the hardcoded `<div>` is unchanged?  It's past my bedtime and in the future I'll stick to writing answers here to when I am fully awake and caffeinated.

Comment: my bed time also.  I'll check tomorrow morning... this makes alot of sense

Comment: sorry it was totally your answer.  I since found that I should make a directive and use the "link" property to append jquery.